# Difficulty accessing objects in another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm setting a string in a view controller called ViewController and trying to access it somewhere else. This is the code:

ViewController.h

```
NSString *string;

...

@property (retain) NSString *string;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize string;

...

-(void)viewDidLoad {

...

string = @"Test";

}
```

OtherViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

...

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    ViewController *vc;
    vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"String: %@", vc.string);

}
```

However, the log is showing: `String: (null)`. What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: instead of putting it on the view did load, try putting the string '= @"test" in an -init. viewDidLoad only triggers when the view controller is actually called on stage (get viewed), so unless the view it self is called to stage, your string wont be initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit : it doesn't necessarily need to be an NSObject class, if you want to, you could also do this on your viewController class, just be sure to also include

```
-(id)init
```

on your header

---- end of edit

if you're trying to make a class that's accessible to another view controller, why not try NSObject instead of view controller (considering you only need to take that string value)

for instance, lets call that viewController class "global" class

so at global.h, you put up

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalVar : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;


-(id)init;

@end
```

and then, at global.m you put up

```
#import "GlobalVar.h"

@implementation GlobalVar

@synthesize myString;

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"the String"];
    }

    return self;
}



@end
```

after this, everytime you need to access the "myString" object that contained in global class, you could put up

at header :

```
#import "GlobalVar.h"
...
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) GlobalVar *globalVar;
```

at implementation file :

```
@synthesize globalVar;

...
...

self.globalVar = [[GlobalVar alloc]init];
NSString *theString = globalVar.myString;
NSLog(@"content of my string is : %@",theString);
```

there you go ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController` is only called when the `view` is loaded. The `view` is lazily loaded when required e.g. when a call to `vc.view` is made.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but this certainly seems like a code smell to me.

As @Fscheidl points out you are creating a new instance and not accessing an existing instance so this may add to your problem. I still believe your main issue is that you assume `viewDidLoad` is being called just by creating the `viewController`, which is not the case

Comment: Properties are nevertheless only accessible to the one single instance. On allocating `vc`, he creates a entirely new one

Answer (score 0):

You do create a new instance of `ViewController` by calling `[[ViewController alloc] init];` This instance hasn't had `string` even set. You have to access that **exact** instance of `ViewController`.

If you create the instance of `OtherViewController` directly from `ViewController`, you can add the following to `OtherViewController.h`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *previousViewController
```

When creating the `OtherViewController`, you can then set:

```
//alloc and init instance of OtherViewController
myOtherViewController.previousViewController = self;
```

In your `viewDidLoad:` method, you can then access your string as follows:

```
NSLog(@"String: %@", previousViewController.string);
```